# How to create a widget like below in tornado using jinja2

Tags: python, tornado, jinja2, web-frameworks

I want to create a template like the above fig - where the numbers can be varied depending on my input data with a fig also. How can I do this in jinja2 template engine  in tornado web frame work.(Python)

Discription about fig:

Fig contain a box with red color and contain a (Nom : 1) (where the number can be varied depending on the i/p) and also cantain a small fig

Comment: you question does not make much sense.

Comment: Here I want to create a template in Jinja2 Template engine (python : ubuntu ) Where some datas are varied depending on my input

Comment: This is the code i tried in html

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:450px;height:250px;border:1px solid #000;background-color:LightBlue;">


<img border="0" src="sun.png" style="float:right; margin:20px 20px 15px 15px; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; border:0" alt="Pulpit rock" width="150" height="150">
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I 'm comupet some datas from python - I want to import that values to html and print my html page using jinja2 template engine

Comment: have a look at this then: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates